# Внешняя БД и android-приложение

Tags: java, android, база-данных, android-sdk

Как сделать внешнюю БД (которая будет висеть где-то на хостинге) и сделать возможность записывать/читать информацию с нее в android-приложении . Если такое возможно, подскажите как это сделать или поделитесь ссылкой на ресурс. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из новомодных решений - внешняя база данных на Firebase. Из коробки умеет мгновенно синхронизироваться.
https://console.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 4):

1. Стандартным паттерном в таких случаях является развертка веб морды (по умному веб сервиса) над БД и работа с ней из Android, через HTTP. Для обмена данными обычно принято использовать JSON. Ключевые слова для поиска RESTful+JSON
2. Менее популярный метод работа через [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)

Comment: Вариантов масса - можно например EPP еще - будет быстрее

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ